# Summing a number recursively and displaying it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I searched for a solution to this problem quite a bit, but couldn't reach a solution. Would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Ok, so suppose there's a number :-

```
0.001
```

What I want to do is, *add* 0.001 (the same number) to it again and again ever second and also display the change dynamically.

So :-

```
second 1 :- 0.001
second 2:- 0.002
second 3 :- 0.003
```

This has to keep running for *1 hour* and I should be able to see it's value changing dynamically on my web page. How can I achieve this? I did quite a research on using *countup.js*, but no result. I thought of a solution to use ajax, but this would cause a lot of load.
Whats the best that I can do here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Given that the solution is literally one line of code, you need to research some basic javascript before looking at complicated plugins.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
feel free to play with it

```js
var c = 0.000;
var count = document.getElementById('count');
count.innerHTML = c;

// Creates the interval with the name interval
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  c += 0.001
  count.innerHTML = c;

  // Its possible that you will see 0.00300000000007 artifacts
  // You can fix it by converting it to a string and showing only a part

  // count.innerHTML = ("" + c).substring(0, 5);
}, 100) // 1/10 sec for demo

// Clear the interval after one hour
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 1000) // one second for demo
```

```html
counter: <span id="count"></span>
```

Comment: How can i make it automatically stop after 1 hour?

Comment: @RinSupreme, added the stop feature

Answer (score 0):

[simple with js](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/dj4exou2/)

```js
var value = 0.001; //value to start
var inc = 0.001; //increment
var end = 0.010; //to test , 1 hour is 3.600
var _interval = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('midiv').innerHTML = value;
  value += inc;
  value = parseFloat(value.toFixed(3));
  if (value > end) {
    clearInterval(_interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="midiv">
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<div id="display"></div>

var number = 1;
var timer = function(){
    number++;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = parseFloat(number / 1000);
    if(number < 3600){ // 1 hour check
        setTimeout(timer,1000);
    }
};

timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bluegrass99/yx0tt7vp/) using rxjs

```
var interval = 1000;
var totrun = 60*1000

var v = 0

const source = Rx.Observable
.interval(interval) 
.takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(totrun)); 


const subscription = source.subscribe(
  t => {
    v=v+0.001          
    $('#v').html(v);    
  },
  err => console.log('Error: ' + err),
  () => console.log('Completed'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
             
     var old = parseFloat($(".number").html());
     var newValue = old + 0.001;
     $(".number").html(newValue);

 }, 1000);

 // this clears the interval loop from firing after 1 hour
 setTimeout(function(){
     clearInterval(interval);
 }, 3600000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">0.001</div>
```

That should do the trick

Comment: How can I make it stop after 1 hour?'

Comment: @RinSupreme check my edit, i added a way to do that

Comment: @labago you dont need jquery for such a simple thing..

Comment: @webdeb true i just think its easier to read

Comment: Code doesn't work. Says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`. And yep, I included jquery.

Comment: @RinSupreme it does work, you might need to refresh the page to see my updated post

Comment: Still does not work. Shows 0.027000000000000017 now

Comment: Why not just `var num = 0.001
,interval = setInterval(function(){ 
     num += 0.001;
     $(".number").text(num.toFixed(3));
 }, 1000);`

Comment: @mplungjan ya that works better